# Почему с использованием многопоточности быстродействие программы не растет?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Решил сравнить скорости вычисления с использованием многопоточности и без использования. Для этого один и тот же цикл запустил обычным способом без применения многопоточности, во втором случае (закомментировано) запустил пять потоков. Если я всё правильно понимаю, то программа во втором случае должна выполняться в 5 раз быстрее. Но почему-то когда запускаю 5 потоков, программа выполняется очень долго, а может и бесконечно, выполнения я не дождался. Вопрос: почему так, может в коде что-то не учел?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        MyFirstThread mft = new MyFirstThread();
        mft.run();
    //        Thread t1 = new Thread(mft);
    //        Thread t2 = new Thread(mft);
    //        Thread t3 = new Thread(mft);
    //        Thread t4 = new Thread(mft);
    //        Thread t5 = new Thread(mft);
    //        t1.start();
    //        t2.start();
    //        t3.start();
    //        t4.start();
    //        t5.start();

    }


    public static class MyFirstThread implements Runnable {
        public volatile int t = 0;

        public void run() {
            Date date1 = new Date();
          while (t<1000000000){
              t+=1;
          }
          Date date2 = new Date();
            System.out.println(date2.getTime()-date1.getTime());
        }
    }
}
```

И в заключении еще вопрос: правильно ли я понимаю, что если, например, у меня 1-ядерный процессор, то из преимуществ использования многопоточности быстродействие я не получаю?

Comment: Во-первых, если один и тот же код запустить 5 раз, даже параллельно, он выполняться в 5 раз быстрее не будет. В лучшем случае выполнится с той же скоростью. Во-вторых, вы не учитываете накладные расходы на многопоточность.

Comment: Не уверен что ускорение возможно при такой постановке задачи. У тебя 1 процесс - на него ос выделяет приоритет; Какая разница на сколько потоков этот приоритет делить на 1 на 5 или на 10, рабочее-время выделенное по этому приоритету одинаково. (могу ошибаться)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Состояние гонки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Операция увеличения `t`:

```
t+=1;
```

Не атомарная. Она фактически состоит из двух операций: считывания значения и присвоения нового значения. Пока один поток считал значение и увеличивает его на единицу, другой поток также считывает это же значение и пытается присвоить его заново. Более того «отстающий» поток может затереть результаты «опережающего»:

```
Поток 1: получил значение t=1
Поток 2: получил значение t=1
Поток 2: записал значение t=2
Поток 2: получил значение t=2
Поток 2: записал значение t=3
Поток 1: записал значение t=2
```

Таким образом потоки не помогают друг другу, по очереди увеличивая `t`, а скорее мешают. Добавьте к этому расходы на доступ к общей памяти и получите объяснение сильного падения производительности.

`volatile` здесь недостаточно. Можно синхронизировать доступ к `t` (сделать увеличение атомарным), но это приведет к блокировкам между потоками и сведет на нет преимущества многопоточности. Улучшить производительность можно за счет изменения логики разделения труда между потоками. Например, если каждый поток будет считать собственный счетчик, а выходить по условию общей суммы.